# Login to a site using HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, authentication, httpurlconnection

I am seeking your expertise to know whether below is achievable.

I am trying to connect to an Webpage (not a login page) using Java HttpUrlConnection. Also i have passed credentials on Basic Authentication.

The connection is automatically redirected to login page with Response code 302.

I need to know if i can submit the credentials on the login page and again redirect to my actual page?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Login using HttpURLConnection is achievable.

However, you will need reverse engineer the specific details for the login protocol / sequence *for each specific site* in order to figure out how to make programmatic site login work.

This is generally not hard to do.  You start by carefully examining the source of the pages and the requests that your browser makes when you login to the site.

Comment: No, I will do it my self, Thanks for your comments